# No Authors for custom post type

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to implement custom post type in Wordpress.

plugin: **Advanced Custom Fields**

```
    register_post_type('acf', array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        '_builtin' =>  false,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
        'query_var' => "acf",
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
        ),
        'show_in_menu'  => false,
    ));
```

However, my another plugin, which displays only user's content (posts, pages, media...) is disabling also the metaboxes created by this plugin.

This is the code of the small plugin which displays user's stuff (thanks goes to another post and person)

```
function content_for_current_author($query) {

if($query->is_admin) {
    global $user_ID;
    $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'content_for_current_author');
```

Users now can't see metaboxes which I created as admin on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the post type in the `pre_get_post` filter:

(Not sure about `global $user_ID;`, just reproduce that part of your code)

```
function content_for_current_author($query) {

    if($query->is_admin) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('acf', 'another-custom-pot', 'page', 'post') );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'content_for_current_author');
```

Details in [WP Query documentation for Type Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Also, your custom post type dosn't support custom fields, maybe that is hte reason of meta boxes don't showing. Not sure here because I don't know how ACF works. Try to add support for custom fileds to your post type; change the support argument to:

```
supports' => array(
            'title',
            'custom-fields'
        ),
```

Comment: No luck, and with this added, even media files aren't displayed anymore. And main thing, meta-boxes created by Advanced Custom Fields ('acf' post type) didn't appear. Wouldn't it be possible to force this post type to display to all users?

Comment: or what about giving exception into the code above?

Comment: Obviously, if you copy and paste the code I posted, attachments are not included because `attachemnt` post type is not set in the `post_type` argument of the query. You must include every type os post you want in the `$query->set('post_type')` or set to `any` to include all. See details in [WP Query documentation for Type Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters). About your issue with meta boxes created by ACF plugin, you should ask in ACF forums. Instead, if you are coding the meta boxes show us the code you are trying and we will help you.

Comment: Understand. I created these meta-boxes through ACF. I have already wrote them =) (Yep, I could probably do that as first thing). It'll be maybe easier than it seems.